# Surface charge density of a conducting plate

Tags: electrostatics

I know that surface charge density is *inversely* proportional to the radius of curvature of a surface, but since the radius of curvature of a conducting sheet is **∞**, and I know its charge density is not 0, is this an exception or is there something wrong in the way I understood the relation?

Comment: I think the difference is between a closed and open surface. Also for a truly infinite conducting surface (whose steady state is a uniform charge distribution $\sigma > 0$)the total charge when integrated diverges ($Q = \int \sigma da =\sigma \int da = \infty$).

Comment: Oh, that's something I didn't know, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering a charge $Q$ on a spherical surface of radius $r$, due to $Q= \int \sigma df $, where $\sigma$ is surface charge density and $df$ the surface element one gets indeed

$$\sigma = \frac{Q}{4\pi r^2}$$

Now if the radius $r$ is varied and the charge $Q$ is kept constant one can indeed observe that the surface charge density changes like $\sim \frac{1}{r^2}$. To give a more intuitive picture, one either expands or contracts the sphere where the charge is put on and the surface charge density shows this behaviour.

If a charge is put on a flat conductor one can apply the a similar picture comparing it with a spherical surface with a $r=\infty$. For a flat conductor contracting or expanding the spherical surface (and keeping this way the charge $Q$ constant and varying $r$ ) corresponds to a finite perpendicular shift (whose value we will call $a$)   of the conductor. However, $r$ is not changed by such a shift. Or in mathematical terms:  $r +a = \infty +a= \infty$. So the $\sigma$, the surface charge density does not change.

Comment: Thank you. So I understand that it is a uniform charge density. But what would the value of the charge density be? For example, for all values of Q, as long as r = ∞, we get σ =0 applying σ=Q4π/r^2, whether the value of r changes or not.

Comment: A full spherical surface of $r=\infty$ does not exist. However, the formula $\sigma = \frac{Q}{4\pi r^2}$ assumes that a full spherical surface in order to be correct. A flat conductor is always of limited extension whose value can be called $S$. With this in mind, $\sigma=Q/S$. Comparing a flat conductor to a spherical surface of $r=\infty$ is only an analogy, actually it is only locally valid. And as it is only locally valid, it cannot be used for computations.

Comment: That clears things up. Thanks!